# How to append html content using angular Include

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a requirement where we need to show/hide a div conditionally. But, here the div is created dynamically based on click event. I used `ng-include`, but this always replaces the content for every click event.

In *analyticsDetail.html*, if `report` object exists (which I am setting in controller), then include *metricsReport.html* page.

```
analyticsDetail.html
<div id="metricsReport" ng-if="report" ng-include="'pages/metricsReport.html'"></div>


metricsReport.html
<div id="{{report.name | removeSpaces}}" ng-init="runReport(report);">{{report.name}}</div>
```

Click event is triggering from a list of menus which is also generated dynamically.

```
<div class="leftlist" style="border: none;">
<div ng-click="loadMitricsView(menus.report)" ng-repeat="menus in mgroup.menus" class="menuitems">{{menus.name}}</div>
```

Controller Method:

```
$scope.loadMitricsView = function(report) {
    $scope.report = report[0];
}
```

Comment: Where/when the click events happened?

Comment: Have you tried to use `ng-show/hide` instead `ng-if` for this case? With a `ng-if` you are removing the element from the DOM and this will reinitialize the `ng-include` content always.

Comment: yes, have tried `ng-show/hide`  also. But, `ng-include` replacing the content.